# Rails 3.1, get No route matches [GET] "/" when trying to link_to XLS document in public directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I use link_to helper with a XLS document in PUBLIC directory.

I have migrated recently my rails APP from version 3.0.10 to version 3.1.8

since migration, I live problem when I refer my XLS document with the link_to helper.

I get the following error: 
**Started GET "/public/IMCClients.xls" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-19 13:11:35 -0400
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/public/IMCClients.xls"):**

How can I resolve my problem?

Comment: can you paste your link_to helper code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see if this works `<% link_to "Link Name", root_path+"/IMCClients.xls" %>`

Comment: Thanks for your help Raghu.  Problem resolved, but without the /.  My link look like: <%= link_to t("link.imcdoc"), root_path + "IMCClients.xls" %>